# Python How to Stop Automatic Reduction of Fractions

Tags: python, reduce, fractions

I was wondering if there is any way I can stop Python doing automatic reduction of fractions when using the fractions module. For example:

```
>>> import fractions
>>> fractions.Fraction(8,16)
Fraction(1, 2)
```

I would like to preserve the fraction as Fraction(8,16). Is that possible using a custom class or similar? Any sample code will be much appreciated!

Thank you!
Sumant

Comment: Why do you need to maintain the original numerator and denominator at all? You could simply track those separately, but for the normal usecases of `fractions.Fraction()` it makes no sense whatsover.

Comment: It is actually to create a pupil worksheet for Maths activities. It will make more sense for students who want to learn adding fractions, for instance: 1/2 + 1/6 = 8/12. When I do this in Python the answer will be 2/3 instead of 8/12.

Comment: @SumantMurugesh: for something so simple, why don't you just do the math yourself, or write an ImproperFraction class?

Comment: Further describe the data type you want. What operations do you need to perform on it? Why does a 2-tuple not suffice?

Answer (score 1):

h/t ["bowlofred" at python-forum.io](https://python-forum.io/thread-30176-post-127884.html#pid127884) for this undocumented hack:

```py
from fractions import Fraction

def add_nonormal(a: Fraction, b: Fraction) -> Fraction:
    if a.denominator == b.denominator:
        c_numerator = a.numerator + b.numerator
        c_denominator = a.denominator
    else:
        c_numerator = a.numerator*b.denominator + b.numerator*a.denominator
        c_denominator = a.denominator*b.denominator
    return Fraction(c_numerator, c_denominator, _normalize=False)

def sub_nonormal(a: Fraction, b: Fraction) -> Fraction:
    return add_nonormal(a, -b)

def mul_nonormal(a: Fraction, b: Fraction) -> Fraction:
    c_numerator = a.numerator*b.numerator
    c_denominator = a.denominator*b.denominator
    return Fraction(c_numerator, c_denominator, _normalize=False)

def reciprocal_nonormal(x: Fraction) -> Fraction:
    return Fraction(*reversed(x.as_integer_ratio()), _normalize=False)

def div_nonormal(a: Fraction, b: Fraction) -> Fraction:
    return mul_nonormal(a, reciprocal_nonormal(b))

assert add_nonormal(Fraction(1, 6), Fraction(2, 6)).as_integer_ratio() == (3, 6)
assert add_nonormal(Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(1, 6)).as_integer_ratio() == (8, 12)
```

This is also useful if you're "mis"-using `Fraction` for extensive math, and all the unnecessary intermediate `gcd` calls start to bog down operation.

Comment: I am curious if there's any quick way to at least factor out common powers of `2` to reduce ballooning 